# Force printing on new line in bash in a while loop when using 2 commands

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I've been trawling the web and I can't seem a way force a second command to print on a new line in a while loop, using bash. Here's an example file:

```
$ cat testing
foo
bar
testing
hello
```

Here's an example loop:

```
$ cat testing | while read line; do echo -e $line, $(echo $line); done
foo, foo
bar, bar
testing, testing
hello, hello
```

I'd like to loop to print everything on a new line, like:

```
foo
foo
bar
bar
testing
testing
hello
hello
```

I'd like this to include for if the output for the second command, the one in brackets, has more than one interation as an output, to also print this on a new line.

Thanks,

Comment: Why `echo -e $(echo $line)` at all? What's the point of that? Also `,` is not (generally) meaningful to the shell. What do you think `echo -e $line, $(echo $line)` is being seen as by the shell?

Comment: As for example if the second command in the $(cmd) is returning a large amount of results, it seems to print them next to each other and not on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; echo "$line"; done <testing
```

or even

```
sed p testing
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the awk version

```
awk '1;1'
```

prints each line twice.